# Overlapping DialogFragment, recreated in wrong order when orientation changes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, orientation-changes

I'm using two overlapped `DialogFragment` (I know, maybe it is not a good design pattern), and I have problem on orientation changes.

[image]

When the orientation changes, the most external `DialogFragment` (the smallest) go behind the most internal.

The simplest solution for my application can be to dismiss the most external DialogFragment, but I'm not able to do it, since `setRetainInstance(false)` seems not working with `DialogFragment`.

The fragment are added dinamically, calling:

```
DialogFragment fragment = CreateEventFragment.newInstance(0);
fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), CreateEventFragment.FRAGMENT_TAG);
```

Comment: You can remove both fragments from hierarchy instead of dismissing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, overriding the `onSaveInstanceState`, in this way:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if(outState==null)
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

Now, after orentation changes, the outmost `DialogFragment` is mainteined external, so they are recreated in the right order.